# XML not getting saved just the time it is saved in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am using XDocument.Save(fileName) method to save the already present xml file at the same location after doing some changes to it and recreating it. Now the scenario is that when user is done with the changes and the file is open in the text editor, sometimes the xml is saved just at the same time and user gets a prompt in the editor that File has been saved. Do you want to reload? but some times it takes to get the prompt in editor which confuses the user if the file has been saved or not. It means it is taking time to save the file. Why is it so.

Comment: A lack of newlines can also confuse the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using FileStream object, and then flushing it.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Truncate))
{
    xmlDoc.Save(fs);
    fs.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Niranjan for the reply. The solution proposed by you is working fine for single xml file but if I have a collection of files and saving these files one by one in that case it is taking time as mentioned in my original post. Any workarounds ?